# Is the Yearling badge working correctly?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I've noticed that over the past 2-3 days, I've earned the Yearling badge (earn 200 rep in a one-year period) at least 4-5 times, and just for [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208118/686) post. While I appreciate your appreciation ;-), I can't imagine that's working as intended.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I should have searched beyond this site's meta. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43244/131214) answers my question.

Comment: Assuming you gain no rep, you will get 9 badges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All is good. You get one per year, as long as you have 200 times the number of years reputation. Therefore, suddenly happening upon a lot of rep can trigger multiple to be awarded around the same time. To repost the link you found: [Details on how the Yearling badge works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43240/323179)